# Search word in sentence by pattern

Tags: .net

I'm working on the app to search any information. For example, user write

> Whats the weather today?

or

> Whats the weather in London?

I will have a set of questions in advance. And it's easy to find out what I want to look for, for example in this case by keyword `weather`. But i don't know how to determine what to look for (weather today or weather in London). The question may by `weather today` or `weather in london`. I thought that I would have "masks", for example `weather in [CITY]` or `weather on [DAY]` and I would compare sentence with masks.

Can I use regex? Or do you know any algorithms that could help me?

Thanks for your advices

Comment: This is really broad.  Have you done any prior research?

Comment: Yes, I try to find out how to solve this problem. I thought I'd find the answer faster here, at least the direction to go.

Comment: If you want us to help out, I would recommend trying one of the methods you put above (Regex, etc). I don't want to give a right/wrong answer here, but it might be more beneficial if you try something on your own, and if you get stuck, to come back.